# JQuery Plug-In to advanced handle drag and drop for my special need

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I know that I can use the JQueryUI Drag and Drop with some of my custom function for my issue, but before I myself make my brain cazy I want to find some plug-in fit my need. Now is the description about my work:

- I have 5 Dragable and 5 Dropable.
- Each Dropable only accept 1 Dragable, so when you drop a second Dragable, the old Dragable will return to the start position.
- When you drop a Dragable, it wil auto placed at the center of the Dropable.

Any recommendations?
Thanks for all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery UI drag and drop has this feature. You need to write a little bit of code to achieve what you want.

Link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert.